# When to set shadowPath value for custom UITableViewCell with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell with bg, title, subtitle, description and tick button. Subtitle and description is optional, so cell height is dynamic. Also, I use AutoLayout.

I want to add shadow to the "Bg" (UIImageView)

[image]

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()

bg.layer.cornerRadius = 3
bg.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1450980392, green: 0.1490196078, blue: 0.368627451, alpha: 1).cgColor
bg.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0,height:4)
bg.layer.shadowRadius = 1
bg.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1

bg.layer.masksToBounds = false
layer.masksToBounds = false
clipsToBounds = false
isOpaque = false

let shadowBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bg.frame.width, height: bg.frame.height)
bg.layer.shadowPath = CGPath(roundedRect: shadowBounds, cornerWidth: 3, cornerHeight: 3, transform: nil)
bg.layer.shouldRasterize = true
}
```

I want to use shadowPath to increase performance of TableView. Without shadowPath shadow works as expected.

[image]

If I set bg.layer.shadowPath value, height of the shadow is very tall.

[image]

If I print bg.frame.height inside awakeFromNib it will be 167 as in storyboard. But the cell bg image height without description is about 78. 
**How to bind shadowPath size to bg image size?**

I noticed that cell’s contentView.frame.height after calling super.layoutSubviews() is 95 points as expected but the background image (child of contentView) height is much taller (147 pt) than contentView.

Comment: you can do that layout subview methos or call setNeedsLayout

Comment: try to set **masksToBounds** to true

Comment: If I set masksToBounds to true shadow dissapears.

Comment: also **clipsToBounds**  to true ?

Comment: It did not helps.

Comment: instead of **height: bg.frame.height** set it to **height: bg.bounds.height**

Comment: Already tried. bg.bounds.height is equal to bg.frame.height.